# How to configure: WS-AT Narayana standalone?

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, transactions, distributed-transactions

I want to use Narayana - WS-Transaction in a standalone springboot app that calls two different Webservics in a single transaction. One of those internally uses db resource for insert/update.

Is standalone-WSAT-possible with narayana? If yes :

- How do I configure **UserTransaction**, **PlatformTransactionManger** etc in Springboot java config?
- How to add those two WebServiceTemplate (s) as "WS-AT transactional resources"?

The example here does not show those beans: https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/spring/stock-market-with-narayana-spring-boot/src/main

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no Narayana Spring Boot WS-AT quickstart that would show you how to utilize the technology. WS-AT is the best integrated in WildFly application server. You  can find the Narayana quickstarts containing examples of running it at https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/XTS. If you consider using Spring Boot then in general it should be possible but you need to configure all the integration on your own. That's not prepared and/or maintained by the Narayana team. You can get inspiration at quickstarts of itegrating Narayana with Spring Boot at https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/spring. If you want to check how the integration to WildFly is done then a good starting point could be https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/xts/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/xts/XTSSubsystemAdd.java.